# Facebook site plugin in outlook signature

Tags: facebook, outlook

I would like to implement a facebook site plugin in my email signature, the pluginis provided by facebook itself and the code is this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fproagent.at%2F&tabs=keine&width=340&height=130&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=false&appId" width="340" height="130"
    style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Is there any possibility to do this? I tried it with the Bells and Whistles application for outlook but that didn't work.

Thank you for having a look at it!

Comment: Those plugins rely heavily on JavaScript - and when viewing e-mails, JS code is usually not executed.

Comment: `<iframe>` does not work in email. You could build a version of that as a signature far faster than you could to implement it as a plug-in. You could automate a snapshot of your FB info and automatically save it as an image and link to that if the information changes frequently.

Comment: That's what I did for now, thanks for the information!